# Is there a numerical integration function through data points in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Like the title says, I was wondering if anyone knows of a javascript function that can do numerical integration on an x and y vector of data points?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you gave an exemple, it would be more understandable

Comment: Hi Kevin, definitely! I have a file of a fitted density graph. I therefore have a bunch of x values and corresponding y values that make a density curve when they are graphed. I would like to calculate the cumulative density for a given user input. There is a function in R that I currently use called "integrate.xy", however, I am making this a web app so I am working on transforming my code to js.

Comment: No, there are no such tools built into JS. It surely is available in some library, but asking for that is off topic on Stack Overflow. Maybe you will have luck searching for a JS port of the R function.